# database restore failing with move

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to restore a database backup but getting error:

> *Restore failed for Server 'ASIF-VAIO'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)*
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: File 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\uwa.mdf' is claimed by
>   'Aston_Fresh_log'(2) and 'Aston_Fresh'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be
>   used to relocate one or more files. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)*

Comment: I am using SSMS to restore it.

Comment: I am using SSMS for taking backup and same for restoring backup

Comment: So are you just simply restoring, or are you setting specific parameters / values? It looks like the files you want to restore to already exist and are in use on your system - try defining new file names for your restore

Comment: I put backup file with different name in sql server backup folder and trying to restore but same error.

Comment: Looks like a database is already using those files. Have you tried using the "replace" restore option? Or as it says try the move option. These should be settable through SMO, are definitely settable through SQL, and I think through the SSMS dialog.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When restoring, you need to be sure to

- pick a new database name that doesn't already exist (unless you want to overwrite that pre-existing database)

[image]

- you tick the `Overwrite` option in the `Options` tab page and define **valid** and new file names for the `.mdf` and `.ldf` file so that you don't accidentally overwrite another database on your system:

[image]

Comment: I've made sure of all your suggestions to be right and I still get the error.

Comment: I figured out my error: I was using same file names for Data and Objects files. So anyone else having the same problem, make sure your file names are valid, new and are not identical for the different files your have to restore (like Data, Objects or Log).

Comment: A little tip I just found. When you change the "Restore As" file names, it doesn't append the .mdf/.ldf extension so I was effectively trying to set them to same file. Specifying the extension cleared it.

Comment: For SQL Server 2008 R2 open the 'Options' and for File Name 'ARCHIVE_XX' Select Restore As change to different filename (.mdf).

Comment: None of the above or below answers worked for me, but i was able to get around this problem by creating new folders within my exisitng data and log folders, so they were completely separate from all other data and log files...very strange!

Comment: In my case i had to use the file browser dialog in "Restore as" section to rename the file.Merely renaming the path displayed in the text box did not work.

Answer (score 7):

This post has some excellent answers but I don't believe my solution was covered here, or I didn't understand the answer/comment.

However, when I encountered this error I was restoring a database with 2 indexes (Primary and Index). The issue was that when restoring it had created two .ndf files, one for each index, but had named them the same thing.

So essentially I had two "Restore As" files restoring to "D:\MSSQLDATA\DatabaseName.ndf.

To overcome this I had to change one of the file names, so for example I changed

```
 Index      |    D:\MSSQLDATA\DatabaseName.ndf
 Primary    |    D:\MSSQLDATA\DatabaseName1.ndf
```

having unique file names fixed this for me.

Comment: This did the trick for me. generating the restore script and editing the duplicated files. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me : giving a different name to each MDF and LDF file in the script section.

```
MOVE N'R_Data' 
  TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Build51_Testing_db1.mdf',

MOVE N'R_audit' 
  TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Build51_Testing_db2.mdf',
```

etc...

Originally suggested by Alberto Morillo

Answer (score 1):

I know it's long since the last answer, but I happened to search in google for solution for this problem.
What did it for me, was scripting the restore (changing file name did not do the trick) and manually changing the filenames in code

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DB_NAME] 
FILE = N'[name]',  
FILE = N'[name1]',
FILE = N'[name2]' 
FROM  DISK = N'[file_path]' 
WITH  FILE = 1m
MOVE N'[name]' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\\[name].mdf',
MOVE N'[name1]' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\\[name1].mdf',
MOVE N'[name2]' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\\[name2].mdf',
MOVE N'[logname]' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\\[logname].ldf'
NOUNLOAD,
REPLACE,
STATS = 10
GO
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue and it's not the above, try under the Restore Options > Files, check the Relocate all files to folder checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was already  a `.mdf` and `.ldf` file in my `\DATA` folder, so I had to create two new files:

```
New-Item C:\path\to\sql\DATA\NewDatabase.mdf
New-Item C:\path\to\sql\DATA\NewDatabase_log.ldf
```

And then in the SQL manager you need to select those new files when restoring the database.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the database has 2 mdf files. And the error came, because I'm trying to restore both mdf files as the same name.

Just rename the second mdf file, under "Restore As".

[image]